# Problema con ventana modal

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, modal

hola en este proyecto de github:
https://github.com/JamtMaster/voypalla
tengo una ventana modal al hacer clic en el boton login sin embargo cuando lo hago el fondo de la web se va haciendo cada vez mas a la izquierda. miren:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo cuando doy clic en login pasa lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden apreciar hay una gran diferencia entre el scrollbar y el fondo, aclaro que no se salta directamente hacia alla, lo va haciendo poco a poco lo hice muchas veces para que apreciaran la diferencia de forma inmediata.

el boton tiene esta linea de codigo:

```html
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"> <span>Login</span></button>
```

y el contenido de la ventana lo siguiente:

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="modal fade" id="login"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
   <div class="modal-dialog" >
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
       <h2 class="text-center" class="modal-title">Iniciar sesion </h2>
    </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="text-center social-btn">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><b>Facebook</b></a>
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><b>Twitter</b></a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-google"></i><b>Google</b></a>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

donde podria estar el fallo? agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Comment: No sé si ya hayas solucionado el error o no, he visto el código en Git y está correcto, deberías revisar nuevamente, fíjate en todas las dimensiones, que todas sean responsivas.

Comment: inspeccione la pagina mientras navegaba por ella en el navegador y me percate que a la etiqueta body se le agrega la clase style="padding-right: 15px" en ejecucion y es por eso que se va moviendo sin embargo el codigo no se encuentra en el archivo original que podria hacer para evitar que se genere

Comment: veo que has debido arreglarlo.

Comment: no, no lo he arreglado, el problema persiste